# Converging Trajectories and Sufficiency for Optimality

Tags: optimization, dynamic-games, optimal-control

(The question is loosely relatet to this [thread](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/dynamic-optimization-what-if-the-second-order-condition-does-not-hold/6063?noredirect=1#comment7370_6063).)

In the [paper](http://www.beijer.kva.se/PDF/93942267_Disc152.pdf) "Feedback Equilibria for a class of non-linear Differential Games" by Mäler et al. it is stated (p. 14)

> In fact sufficiency is satisfied for trajectories converging to the locally stable steady states of the cooperative solution and open-loop equilibria.

- Can someone elaborate on this statement?

Say, I haven't checked for sufficiency. However, I'm able to approximate the saddle path by the first order conditions. That is, the dynamic system converges to the (unique) fixed point for a given initial condition.

- Is the sufficiency for optimality then given?